# SharePoint 2010 Motools JavaScript incompatibility

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I created a JavaScript Slideshow base on [Slideshow2](https://code.google.com/p/slideshow/) using Mootools. It works great stand-alone. I decided to incorporate it into my SharePoint 2010 Master Page and at first glance it was working great, but for some strange reason other native SharePoint javascript code on the page stopped working. Some JavaScript code such as the “Create” button from “View All site content” does nothing and some drop downs from the global navigation menu. I first noticed when I tried to approve the saved master.page and when I clicked on Approve nothing happened.

I began to delete all my JavaScript code and from process of elimination noticed that just by leaving the line: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/_catalogs/javascript/mootools-1.3.2-core.js"></script>` causes the error. Every other line doesn’t seem to affect the other JavaScript code. I even substituted it to the most recent version and got the same result: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/_catalogs/javascript/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js"></script>`

Comment: It's very clear from you post that Mootools js is conflicting with SharePoint's standard JS, and are you going to show the slideshow in every page of your site? why do you need mootools in master page then? I dont know how much you are affectionate with Mootools and if you are going to need Mootools for some other purpose, but I have used some other jQuery plugin for slideshow, and those work like a charm with SharePoint

Comment: Not overly attached to Mootools, but I had a couple of slideshows based on it when I had the Intranet on SharePoint 2007. I AM looking for an alternative that allows for multiple instances on same page with captions, links, and the ability to change the transition (Simple right to left slide), though. If you can recommend any that are compatible with SharePoint 2010 and fit my specs mentioned, that would be great.